# MySQL join two table if second table is not empty

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like below

### table 1: users

```
id   name 
1    John
2    Jane
3    Mery
4    Alpha
```

### table 2 : notes

```
id   note         owner created
1    alpha alpha    1   2013-02-03 10:30
2    yeah yeah..    2   2013-02-03 10:35
3    crap crap..    2   2013-02-03 10:50
2    yeah yeah..    3   2013-02-03 10:50
3    blah blah..    3   2013-02-03 10:55
```

Now i want to show in a list all the users with their latest notes
like below

```
id   name     note
1    John     alpha alpha
2    Jane     crap crap..
3    Mery     blah blah..
4    Alpha
```

How can I get this in one query? 
(PS: I am using PHP for scripting)

Comment: What does this question have to do with database "administration"?

Comment: @SalmanA Please look at our FAQ and /About page.  We are also about advanced SQL/querying, and database design among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT U.Id, U.Name, N.Note
FROM Users U
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT Owner, Max(created) maxCreated
         FROM Notes
         GROUP BY Owner) MaxN ON U.Id = MaxN.Owner
   LEFT JOIN Notes N ON U.Id = N.Owner AND N.Created = MaxN.maxCreated
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, But What if the note is empty for a user?
like in the example user 4?

Comment: Add a LEFT JOIN instead -- I'll edit...

Answer (score 3):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2fd6/6)

```
select users.*, notes.note from users
LEFT JOIN
(
select owner,max(created) as mc from notes group by owner
) t on users.id=t.owner 
LEFT JOIN notes on t.owner=notes.owner and t.mc=notes.created
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the latest `created` date for each owner.

```
SELECT  a.*, x.*
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  b.*
            FROM    notes b INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  owner, MAX(created) max_date
                        FROM    notes
                        GROUP   BY owner
                    ) c ON  b.owner = c.owner AND
                            b.created = c.max_date
        ) x ON a.ID = x.owner
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48d7/11)

Comment: Perhaps this post may be answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711127/problem-with-joining-to-an-empty-table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, b.note, MAX (b.createdDate)
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN notes b
            ON a.iD = b.Owner
group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this also.

```
 SELECT users.id ,users.name,notes.created FROM users
    LEFT JOIN notes ON
    users.id=notes.owner
    inner JOIN
    (
                            SELECT  OWNER, MAX(created) max_date
                            FROM    notes
                            GROUP   BY OWNER) sq
    ON notes.created=sq.max_date
    and notes.owner=sq.OWNER
```